# Does Amazon provide subscription service for magazines?

Tags: amazon

I would like to know if Amazon provides any subscription service for Magazines to be able to read on my Kindle devices!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I subscribe to a few tech mags not available in our area via my Android Kindle app, so I assume it is available on all kindle related apps and devices.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a link](http://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=magazine%20kindle&tag=googhydr-20&index=digital-text&hvadid=30783118195&hvpos=1t1&hvexid=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=12149920248451921335&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=b&hvdev=c&ref=pd_sl_1iny88wfl8_b) to the Kindle magazine subscription page; they appear to have several thousand magazines available.